# change space between footnote line and main text

Tags: spacing, footnotes

How to change space between main text and footnote, so text goes with the line of footnote

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`  We are more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: @Bonnie Why are you suddenly deleting so many of your questions? That's not fair to the people who put effort in answering your questions.

Answer (score 30):

You have to modify the `\skip\footins` length. You can use `addtolength` to add a rubber length or `setlength` to set one.

A couple of examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pc plus 5pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
a\footnote{test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1.2pc plus 5pt minus 2pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
a\footnote{test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{6pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
a\footnote{test} b\footnote{test2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for reference, here is the normal case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
a\footnote{test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

There are other lengths involved in the footnotes styling/creation. E.g. you could also change the `footnotesep` length (which is a rigid and not rubber length), and this will change the amount of space placed at the beginning of each footnote. This will change also the distance between the first footnote and the text/footnote rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{2pc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
a\footnote{test} b\footnote{test2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I suggest that you elaborate on the fact that it is `\skip\footins` and not `\footnoteSEP` (if you understand what I mean)?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti yep

Comment: In particular, in order to get what the OP asks for, you should say something along the lines of `\begingroup \footnotesize \global \skip\footins = \baselineskip \endgroup` (**beware:** I did *not* test this!).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti you lost me. I think you'd better create that kind of answer since I don't understand it, thus I wouldn't be able to be properly credited and possibly correct it if necessary. But thanks

Comment: @moriambar but my text ends somewhere under the center of page, and I can't move footnote under that text..  i tried your codes but it still stays at the bottom of page

Comment: @Bonnie: You didn’t make [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371138/change-space-between-footnote-line-and-main-text#comment916660_371139) explicit in your question: I suggest that you edit it.  Anyway, I’m afraid that is much harder to achieve, since it entails modifying LaTeX’s output routine; I don’t remember, off the top of my head, if there are any packages that provide what you are asking for.

Comment: @Moriambar: as you see, it turned out that I misunderstood the OP’s request.

Comment: @moriambar I added a photo if u can understand now what I meant

Comment: What is meant by rubber length?

Comment: @Viesturs a rubber length is one that can be increased or decreased by LaTeX within certain limits, in order to fit more items onto a page or to avoid large white spaces.